# Drag and Drop into WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, webbrowser-control

I'm using .Net 4.0 and I have a `TreeView` from which I want to drag items into embedded `WebBrowser` control, but `WebBrowser` does not support events like `DragEnter` and `DragDrop`.

I've tried to listen to mouseup event on `WebBrowser.Document` but it does not seem to fire when mouse is already down when you move your mouse over webbrowser control.

I've tried to use `Microsoft.Win32.Hooks` to catch mouseup event on `MainForm`but it does not seem to be stable and cursor is changing to "no drop".

I'm now thinking if it is possible to implement my own control for `WebBrowser` which will support drag and drop feature, but struggling to find any working example of it.

What will be the best way to implement this kind of functionality?

**NOTE:**
I was able to implement it by using ItemDrag event handler on TreeView without doing DoDragDrop and then tracking MouseUp event with Microsoft.Win32.MouseHooks and MouseMove event on WebBrowser.Document element.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `dragdrop` (or `mouseup`) client-side event from within the `Document`. (by calling `webBrowser.Document.Body.AttachEventHandler`)

Comment: I've tried that but it does not work if you press mouse button down outside of WebBrowser control and then move mouse inside of it and release it.